# Ways to speed up TextMate on large rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

Is there any way to improve the performance of TextMate when a large project is open? Making it the active app is taking about 10 second each and every time.

Comment: I've only experienced this bad of a stall when working from remote filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you switch to TextMate, it `stats` all of the files in your project.  You can inhibit this behavior (selectively on a per-project or per-domain basis) with the ReMate plugin.

[ReMate](http://ciaranwal.sh/remate/)

Comment: Worked like a charm, and while I've given up on seeing a TextMate 2, this is enough of a fix for right now. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 3):

To speedup opening the project (and also searching in it), you may consider to only include into the project the files you're actually *working* at. All the external libraries that may eventually be in the source tree (or sym-linked into that), which you *don't plan to modify*, may be excluded from the project by putting their folder names into the "Folder Pattern" regular expression in the "Folder Information" form, which can be opened by selecting the top-folder in the TextMate and pressing Cmd+I.

Note, that after doing that, you should do File -> Save Project, and then only open your project in TextMate by actually opening the .tmproject-file:

> open myproject.tmproject

**not** by opening the whole folder in TextMate like this:

> mate .

P.S.: Using sym-links for linking external libraries into your source tree is by itself a handy technique, as those may be separate TextMate projects to work on.

Answer (score 1):

What are you hardware specs? Sounds like a RAM issue to me.

Have you considered using a different application? I have been using [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) for some time now and have to say I really enjoy it.

My application is rather large (60ish objects, 20 some plugins, etc...) and with "OK" laptop specs, it runs pretty well. That, and all of the other functionality that it provides makes it well worth the $79 license.

Comment: That doesn't sound particularly large.

Comment: I've dabbled a bit with Rubymine - may ultimately switch to it.